# Query Optimization Needed to Compare A/c Balances at Two Dates [ADO MS-Access Query]

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, query-optimization, ado

**I want to know balance difference (balance comparing) at the end of two different date.**

I have following table structure in **MS-Access 2003 version (DATABASE VERSION Access2000)**:

---

### Credits

CreditID
TxnDate
PartyID
TxnType
Amount
Comments

---

### Debits

DebitID
TxnDate
PartyID
TxnType
Amount
Comments

---

### Parties

PartyID
PartyName
PartyAddress
PartyContactNo
Description

.

I RUN the QUERY below using VB6 and ADO2, to get Account Balances at the end of two different dates, for comparison purpose.

.

```
SELECT P.PartyID, P.PartyName, 

IIF((SELECT SUM(C.Amount) FROM Credits C WHERE C.PartyID = P.PartyID AND C.TxnDate <= "#31/07/2014#") IS NULL,0,(SELECT SUM(C.Amount) FROM Credits C WHERE C.PartyID = P.PartyID AND C.TxnDate <= "#31/07/2014#"))
-
IIF((SELECT SUM(D.Amount) FROM Debits D WHERE D.PartyID = P.PartyID AND D.TxnDate <= "#31/07/2014#") IS NULL, 0, (SELECT SUM(D.Amount) FROM Debits D WHERE D.PartyID = P.PartyID AND D.TxnDate <= "#31/07/2014#")) AS BalanceOn31Jul2014, 

IIF((SELECT SUM(C.Amount) FROM Credits C WHERE C.PartyID = P.PartyID AND C.TxnDate <= "#31/08/2014#") IS NULL, 0, (SELECT SUM(C.Amount) FROM Credits C WHERE C.PartyID = P.PartyID AND C.TxnDate <= "#31/08/2014#"))
-
IIF((SELECT SUM(D.Amount) FROM Debits D WHERE D.PartyID = P.PartyID AND D.TxnDate <= "#31/08/2014#") IS NULL, 0, (SELECT SUM(D.Amount) FROM Debits D WHERE D.PartyID = P.PartyID AND D.TxnDate <= "#31/08/2014#")) AS BalanceOn31Aug2014 

FROM Parties AS P

ORDER BY PartyName;
```

The above query runs but it is very SLOW.

I want to know is there anyway to optimize the above QUERY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be faster to use `group by` to calculate all the credits and debits in one go:

```
select
    c.PartyID,
    c.PartyName,
    Nz(c.Credit31Jul2014, 0) - Nz(d.Debit31Jul2014, 0) as BalanceOn31Jul2014,
    Nz(c.Credit31Aug2014, 0) - Nz(d.Debit31Aug2014, 0) as BalanceOn31Aug2014
from (
    select
        p.PartyID,
        p.PartyName,
        sum(iif(c.TxnDate <= #31/07/2014#, c.amount, 0)) as Credit31Jul2014,
        sum(iif(c.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#, c.amount, 0)) as Credit31Aug2014
    from
        Parties p
            left outer join
        Credits c
            on p.PartyID = c.PartyID
    group by
        p.PartyID,
        p.PartyName
    ) c left outer join (
    select
        d.PartyID,
        sum(iif(d.TxnDate <= #31/07/2014#, d.amount, 0)) as Debit31Jul2014,
        sum(iif(d.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#, d.amount, 0)) as Debit31Aug2014
    from
        Debits d
    where
        d.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#
    group by
        d.PartyID
    ) d on c.PartyID = d.PartyID
order by
    c.PartyName;
```

You might want to consider storing a balances table, that keeps party balances at various dates, say once a month. That will bound the interval of time you have to sum over.

To see why it is fast. First, for your query, you are essentially running at least 4, possibly 8 selects for every PartyID. You could simplify slightly by using `Nz(sum(xxx), 0)` instead of `Iif(sum(xxx) is null, 0, sum(xxx))`. This would guarantee only 4. Each of these selects needs to read the entire credit or debit table. Now, consider this part of my query in isolation:

```
select
    d.PartyID,
    sum(iif(d.TxnDate <= #31/07/2014#, d.amount, 0)) as Debit31Jul2014,
    sum(iif(d.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#, d.amount, 0)) as Debit31Aug2014
from
    Debits d
where
    d.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#
group by
    d.PartyID
```

This gets the total debit for each party. Imagine being given a ledger and being asked to calculate this. You would use a note book to keep partial results. You would read each ledger item in turn, if it fitted the date criteria you would look in your note book to see if you have a record for this party. If not, you would add one with the amount from the row. If you do you would replace the amount with the amount plus the amount from the row. The key thing to realize, is that you can do all this by only reading the ledger once. With your method, you are reading the ledger multiple times per party.

Comment: The above query gives the following error:"Join expression not supported"

Comment: Thanks for submitting this excellent answer. It runs instantly. My request is to please explain why it runs so fast and make this advanced query comprehensible for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PankajExplorer I've made some effort to explain why it is fast.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Laurence's answer to AVOID Nz/IIf in the 4th and 5th lines of the codes.

Thanks Laurance, without whom I was unable to re-answer this question at this moment.

Hence the Final code that I used is,

```
SELECT cc.PartyID, cc.PartyName,
       (cc.Credit31Jul2014 - dd.Debit31Jul2014) AS BalanceOn31Jul2014,
       (cc.Credit31Aug2014 - dd.Debit31Aug2014) AS BalanceOn31Aug2014
FROM
   (SELECT p.PartyID, p.PartyName,
        SUM(IIF(c.TxnDate <= #31/07/2014#, c.amount, 0)) AS Credit31Jul2014,
        SUM(IIF(c.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#, c.amount, 0)) AS Credit31Aug2014
    FROM Parties p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Credits c ON p.PartyID = c.PartyID
    GROUP BY p.PartyID, p.PartyName) AS cc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT p.PartyID,
        SUM(IIF(d.TxnDate <= #31/07/2014#, d.amount, 0)) AS Debit31Jul2014,
        SUM(IIF(d.TxnDate <= #31/08/2014#, d.amount, 0)) AS Debit31Aug2014
    FROM Parties p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Debits d ON p.PartyID = d.PartyID
    GROUP BY p.PartyID) AS dd
ON dd.PartyID = cc.PartyID
ORDER BY cc.PartyName;
```

.
Thanks to Laurence @Laurence